Significance of Elijah's and Elisha's Crossing of the Jordan River
In 2 Kings 2, Elijah splits the Jordan River to walk to the eastern side and then after Elijah's translation to heaven, Elisha replicates the miracle in reverse order to enter into his minstry.  Could there be any theological or typological meaning behind this event?

Elijah and Elisha are walking the route in reverse order that the people of Israel took when they invaded the Promised Land, finally 'exiting' the Promised Land before Elijah is taken to the 'Land of the Promise' on the chariot of fire.  One could say that Elijah is showing Elisha the vision, the significant places of Israel.  Bethel being where Abram and Isaac both encountered God.  Gilgal where the Israelites were circumcised and had their first 'kosher' Passover since leaving Egypt, Jericho the first stronghold to be overcome, and Jordan where the waters parted.
It is to be noted that they do not walk through the waters, the waters were parted, just like the red sea, and then just like when Joshua led the people through.
Around 1,000 years later these same waters would 'part' when Jesus is baptised, and as the waters are opened, so are the heavens.  A similar thing happens with Elijah and Elisha - the waters part, Elijah is taken, and Elisha is born again into his ministry following in Elijah's footsteps, but with a double portion.
Elisha has to part the Jordan as a sign of his prophetic ministry following in that of Elijah.  Elijah's last act is the part the waters, Elisha's first act is to part those same waters.
The last acts of Jesus are his resurrection and ascension into glory, our first act when we are baptised is to be 'raised up with him and seated in heavenly places' (Ephesians 2:6).

If you would like to format this better, then for formatting tips please look at this meta post on Formatting and this meta post on biblical quotations

The OP's observation is the inner part of a larger Chiasm on which the passage in 2 Kings is constructed.

V1-3: Travel to Bethel


V4: Travel to Jericho






V5: Sons of the prophets speak to Elijah and Elisha










V6: Travel to Jordan














V7: 50 Sons of prophets speak


















V8-10: Jordan parted with cloak






















V11, 12: Elijah taken to heaven, Elisha assumes Elijah' cloak






















V13, 14: Jordan parted with cloak


















V15-17: Sons of prophets speak














V18: Elisha at Jordan










V19, 20: Men of city speak to Elisha






V21, 22:Travel back to Jordan to heal waters


V23-25: Travel to Bethel

Such are very common in the OT literature.  The point of this chiasm, as with any chiasm, is the central part - Elisha assuming the mantle of Elijah as God's appointed prophet.  The rest of the chiasm supports this central idea that Elisha had definitely taken over from Elijah.
